# Use my sql to randomly select exclusive records

Tags: mysql, select

I have a Table A as below

```
id (integer)
follow_up (integer, days under observation)
matched_id (integer)


id   ; follow_up  ; matched_id
1    ; 10              ; 19
1    ; 10              ; 20
1    ; 10              ; 21
2    ; 5               ; 22
2    ; 5               ; 23
2    ; 5               ; 24
2    ; 5               ; 19
2    ; 5               ; 20
3    ; 6               ; 25
3    ; 6               ; 26
3    ; 6               ; 27
4    ; 7               ; 19
4    ; 7               ; 28
4    ; 7               ; 29
```

I would like to limit to 2 records per id, and the records should be randomly picked up and be exclusive for each id. For, example 
matched_id: "19" and "20" were given to id:1, then "19" and "20" should not be given to id:2 
matched_id: "19" was given to id:1, then "19" should not be given to id:4 
and so on for the rest of the table.

require output

```
id   ; follow_up  ; matched_id
1    ; 10              ; 19
1    ; 10              ; 20
2    ; 5               ; 22
2    ; 5               ; 23
3    ; 6               ; 25
3    ; 6               ; 26
4    ; 7               ; 28
4    ; 7               ; 29
```

Please help me. Thank you so much!

Comment: Why do you need this result?

Comment: because I need to run a case control study to find controls who are patients in a hospital that match to cases with a disease, given some matching conditions. After I gave some conditions, I have a table that similar as the above, but there are controls that match to more than 1 case

Comment: So, given the data set above, the range of permissable results is actually very limited? It's basically human sudoku. And follow_up is basically irrelevant to this problem, right?

Comment: because when matched_id is assigned to an id, then I will take the observation time from id given to matched_id, so that both CASE and CONTROL (id and matched_id) have the same follow_up time to event. And I will look for their exposure during the follow_up period. There will come more variables then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very good and very challenging SQL question.

You have a very challenging set of requirements:
  1. No matched_id should appear more than once in the result set
  2. No ID be given more than two matches
  3. The matching be random

We will stick to a pure SQL solution, assuming that you can't return, say, a larger result set and do some filtering using business logic in your implementation language.

First, let's tackle random assignment. Randomly ordering items inside of groups is a fun question. I decided to tackle it by ordering on a SHA1 hash of the data in the row (id, follow_up, matched_id), which will give a repeatable result with a feeling of randomness. (This would be best if there were a column that contained the date/time created or modified.)

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT
    a.id,
    a.follow_up,
    a.matched_id,
    a.rank_hash,
    count(*) rank
  FROM
  (SELECT *, SHA1(CONCAT(id, follow_up, matched_id)) rank_hash FROM TableA) a
  JOIN 
  (SELECT *, SHA1(CONCAT(id, follow_up, matched_id)) rank_hash FROM TableA) b
  ON a.rank_hash >= b.rank_hash
  AND a.id = b.id
  GROUP BY a.id, a.matched_id
  ORDER BY a.id, rank
) groups
WHERE rank <= 2
GROUP BY matched_id
```

This might suffice for your use case if there are sufficient matched_id values for each id. But what if there is a hidden fourth requirement:
  4. If possible, an ID should receive a match.

In other words, what if, as a result of random shuffling, a matched_id was assigned to an id that had several other matches, but further down the result set it was the *only* match for an id? An optimal solution in which every ID were matched with a matched_id was possible, but it never happened because all the matched_ids were used up earlier in the process?

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA
    (`id` int, `follow_up` int, `matched_id` varchar(1))
;

INSERT INTO TableA
    (`id`, `follow_up`, `matched_id`)
VALUES
    (1, 10, 'A'),
    (1, 10, 'B'),
    (1, 10, 'C'),
    (2, 5, 'D'),
    (2, 5, 'E'),
    (2, 5, 'F'),
    (3, 5, 'C')
;
```

In the above set, if IDs and their matches are assigned randomly, if ID 1 gets assigned matched_id C, then ID 3 will not get a matched_id at all.

What if we first find out how many matches an ID received, and order by that first?

```
SELECT 
  a.*,
  frequency
FROM TableA a
JOIN 
( SELECT
    matched_id,
    count(*) frequency
  FROM
    TableA
  GROUP BY matched_id
) b
ON a.matched_id = b.matched_id
GROUP BY a.matched_id
ORDER BY b.frequency
```

This is where a middleman programming language might come in handy to help limit the result set.

But note that we also lost our requirement of randomness! As you can see, a pure SQL solution might get pretty ugly. It is indeed possible combining the techniques outlined above.

Hopefully this will get your imagination firing.

Comment: You are right that the frequency gave me from 54-300 matched_id per id  but if I randomly allocate up to max 2 matched_id per id, there are some id only have 1 matched_id left. That is terrible, and I did not think about it before :( but it is a good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Along with `RAND()` and `MySQL user defined variables` you can achieve this:

```
SELECT 
t.id,
t.follow_up,
t.matched_id
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
    randomTable.*,
    IF(@sameID = id, @rn := @rn + 1,
        IF(@sameID := id, @rn := 1, @rn := 1)
    ) AS rowNumber
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
        *
        FROM tableA
        ORDER BY id, RAND()
    ) AS randomTable
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @sameID := 0, @rn := 0) var
) AS t
WHERE t.rowNumber <= 2
ORDER BY t.id
```

<kbd>[**See Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0768a/1/0)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I ran the mysql, however, there are still some matched_id that are not exclusive, i.e. belong to more than one id.

Comment: So, what's the expected output in this case? Am I missing something?

Comment: hi, the expected output is a table with three columns: distinct matched_id; follow_up; id (id is repeated twice in each row, for example id"1"  for matched_id"19", id"1"  for matched_id"20", id"2"  for matched_id"22", id"2"  for matched_id"23",

Comment: You said earlier `I ran the mysql, however, there are still some matched_id that are not exclusive, i.e. belong to more than one id`. I didn't get it. What's the issue?

Comment: hi, the issue is, for example, when I ran the mysql in a table with thousand records, for example, this distribution can happen:  matched_id"19" and matched_id"20", whereas id"2" retain in id"1" ; whereas matched_id"20" and matched_id"22" retain in id"2". Then matched_id"20" is used twice, but I want this column to have distinct value, for example matched_id"23" and matched_id"22" retain in id"2".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for the specific problem given. It does not scale!

```
SELECT *
  FROM
     ( SELECT a.matched_id m1
            , b.matched_id m2
            , c.matched_id m3
            , d.matched_id m4
         FROM my_table a
         JOIN my_table b
           ON b.matched_id NOT IN(a.matched_id)
         JOIN my_table c
           ON c.matched_id NOT IN(a.matched_id,b.matched_id)
         JOIN my_table d
           ON d.matched_id NOT IN(a.matched_id,b.matched_id,c.matched_id)
        WHERE a.id = 1
          AND b.id = 2
          AND c.id = 3
          AND d.id = 4
     ) x
  JOIN
     ( SELECT a.matched_id n1
            , b.matched_id n2
            , c.matched_id n3
            , d.matched_id n4
         FROM my_table a
         JOIN my_table b
           ON b.matched_id NOT IN(a.matched_id)
         JOIN my_table c
           ON c.matched_id NOT IN(a.matched_id,b.matched_id)
         JOIN my_table d
           ON d.matched_id NOT IN(a.matched_id,b.matched_id,c.matched_id)
        WHERE a.id = 1
          AND b.id = 2
          AND c.id = 3
          AND d.id = 4
     ) y
    ON y.n1 NOT IN(x.m1,x.m2,x.m3,x.m4)
   AND y.n2 NOT IN(x.m1,x.m2,x.m3,x.m4)
   AND y.n3 NOT IN(x.m1,x.m2,x.m3,x.m4)
   AND y.n4 NOT IN(x.m1,x.m2,x.m3,x.m4)
 ORDER 
    BY RAND() LIMIT 1;

+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| m1 | m2 | m3 | m4 | n1 | n2 | n3 | n4 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 20 | 24 | 27 | 29 | 21 | 23 | 26 | 28 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

So, in this example, the pairs are:

```
id1: 20,21
id2: 24,23
id3: 27,26
id4: 29,28
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Can it be generalized for a Table with 530 id, rather than only 4 id as in my example?

Comment: Perhaps you missed the first line of my answer!